# Reading nested curly brackets as part of string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have password like this `iD&amp;NAAY#{.x}NqpzK|%`.

When I am trying to store this in string variable like this

`string password = $"\"iD&amp;NAAY#{.x}NqpzK|%\""`

I am getting a compile time error (invalid expression term) in this part `{.x}`

How can I avoid this and read this password as a full string type?

Comment: You should *double* each `{` and `}`: `$"\"iD&amp;NAAY#{{.x}}NqpzK|%\""` or just *drop* `$` prefix: `string password = "\"iD&amp;NAAY#{.x}NqpzK|%\"";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply don't use an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), that means, define the string without the `$` sign prefix.

When you use the `$` sign prefix, C# is parsing your string, trying to find variable references in it and replace them with variable values. The format for variable references in strings is `{variable_name}`.

### Example

```
var test = "abcd";
var interpolated_string = $"Test: {test}";
```

The variable `interpolated_string` will contain the string `Test: abcd`.

If you remove the `$` sign prefix, the string will not be processed and it will be taken as a literal:

```
var test = "abcd";
var interpolated_string = "Test: {test}";
```

The variable `interpolated_string` will contain the string `Test: {test}` now.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann Good catch, thanks! I'm just working on a Python project :)

Comment: While you're at it: the semicolons are missing at the end of each line ;)